# How to use valgrind in xterm with gdb on Linux (redhat)?

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, valgrind, xterm

How to use valgrind in xterm with gdb on Linux (redhat) ?

The command open a xterm terminal, which disappears immediately.

```
xterm -e gdb valgrind --tool=drd --read-var-info=yes ./star &
```

I need it to do debugging for C++ code.

Thanks

Comment: What is your C++ code, `./star` or something in `valgrind`?

Comment: Quote everything you want to run in `"` quotes and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to debug `valgrind`, the procedure is:

1. Run `xterm -e gdb valgrind &`
2. In the `xterm`, set up your breakpoints and such
3. Start the program with `run --tool=drd --read-var-info=yes ./star`

Comment: Or add `--args` between `valgrind` and its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
xterm -e gdb --args valgrind --tool=drd --read-var-info=yes ./star &
```

assuming you want to debug valgrind itself (which seems unlikely, given the question).

If what you really want to do is debug `./star`, while it is running under `DRD`, that used to be pretty much impossible, but became possible with recent valgrind versions, which have embedded gdbserver.

To do that, you'll want two xterms:

```
xterm -e valgrind --tool=drd --read-var-info=yes --vgdb-error=1 ./star &
xterm -e gdb -ex 'file ./star' -ex 'target remote | /path/to/vgdb' &
```